# How to create new documents with a sphinx extension

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

From a sphinx extension, how do I create new documents (new page) under the current document that called my extension. I.e, I have an extension that is called from a rst file.

Something like:

```
foo.rst
  .. myextension::
```

During myextension, I want to generate new files under foo. Something as:

```
foo/bar.html:
   * Some documentation in a new page
foo/baz.html:
   * More documentation in a new page
```

This is a simplification of my extension, if that helps:

```
class NetYnlInclude(Directive):
    def run(self):
        file = "my_file.txt"     
        self.state.document.settings.record_dependencies.add(file)                     
        parsed_str = parse(file) # Parses the file into a string
        self.state_machine.insert_input(
            statemachine.string2lines(parsed_str), filename)

        paragraph_node = nodes.paragraph()
        return paragraph_node
```

Comment: I think the `autosummary` directive creates new files, you could look up its code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate `.html` files directly I'm not sure how to integrate that with Sphinx.

If you want to generate `.rst` files and you want your new documents to be processed by Sphinx you need to create them at a very early stage in the Sphinx build pipeline.

As far as I understand attaching to the [`build-inited` event](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#event-builder-inited) like [`autosummary` does](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/e976059fd6ab49b1c2784445d7095c9287897724/sphinx/ext/autosummary/__init__.py#L841) is the way to do it.

So your extension needs something like

```py
def setup(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    app.connect('builder-inited', generate)


def generate(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    # write .rst files here
```

Now notice there's no mention of directives anywhere - `generate` has no access to any parsed `.rst` documents, directives etc. because at this point no documented have been parsed yet. If you want to extract information from `.rst` files you need to do parse them manually (which is also what `autosummary does).

Alternatively your extension could accept some configuration options to tell it what files to ingest and what to generate.

For a more complete answer see [this nice blog post](https://sammart.in/post/2021-08-12-sphinx-extension-page-generation/) and a corresponding [complete, self-contained repository with the code](https://github.com/Sam-Martin/sphinx-write-pages-tutorial).